# Noname in attached filename send by Python smtplib

Tags: python, smtp, smtplib

I'm able to send a mail using smtplib. But when I attach a file displayed name is "noname". I m using the below piece of code:

```
attach_file_name = 'archivo.txt'

attach_file = open(attach_file_name, 'rb') 
payload = MIMEBase('application', 'octate-stream')
payload.set_payload((attach_file).read())
encoders.encode_base64(payload) 

payload.add_header('Content-Decomposition', 'attachment', filename=attach_file_name)
message.attach(payload)
```

The code was taken from this [source](https://realpython.com/python-send-email/)

Comment: Try `payload = MIMEBase("application", "octet-stream")`.

Comment: Also, to be like the linked example, you should use `payload.add_header('Content-Decomposition', f'attachment; filename= {attach_file_name}')` (assuming you are using Python 3.6+).

Comment: The header is misspelt, it should be   _'Content-Disposition'_

Comment: snakecharmerb, thanks it it was misspelled. This is solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Ok it's an old question, but here is the answer:

Just change your "Content-Decomposition" in " Content-Disposition", it will work better

The "Content-Decomposition" is around in some forum, hopefully they will decompose soon :)

Answer (score 0):

I think that this might not be relevant but for those who are interested and getting the same problem :

I am using the Google Gmail API for Python. It is much safer as we are dealing with Google Apps. Though SMTP is not a bad option, I seriously recommend the Google API.

I am using the google API example (the one without the attachment) and I realised that the attachment is put only when the text in the subject or the body is NOT a complete string i.e. the string which is being put in the subject or the body is not a single string but an collection of strings.

To explain better :

```
message = (service.users().messages().send(userId='me', body=body).execute())
body = ("Your OTP is", OTP)
```

This (body = (`"Your OTP is", OTP)`) may work for print() command, but it doesn't work for this case. You can change this :

```
message = (service.users().messages().send(userId='me', body=body).execute())
body = ("Your OTP is", OTP)
```

to :

```
CompleteString = "Your OTP is " + OTP
message = (service.users().messages().send(userId='me', body=body).execute())
body = (CompleteString)
```

The above lines make the 2 parts of the body into a single string.

Also : The 'noname' file that is put as an attachment contains only the written string. So, if you follow this :

```
message = (service.users().messages().send(userId='me', body=body).execute())
body = ("Your OTP is", OTP)
```

So all you'll get in the file will be : "Your OTP is "

I am also adding the entire code that I got after modifying the already existing sample code here : https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python

```
from __future__ import print_function
import pickle
import os.path
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import base64

sender = "sender_mail"

print("Welcome to the Mail Service!")
reciever = input("Please enter whom you want to send the mail to - ")
subject = input("Please write your subject - ")
msg = input("Please enter the main body of your mail - ")

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify']
creds = None
if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
    with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
        creds = pickle.load(token)
# If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
if not creds or not creds.valid:
    if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
        creds.refresh(Request())
    else:
        flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
            'credentials.json', SCOPES)
        creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
    # Save the credentials for the next run
    with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
        pickle.dump(creds, token)
service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds)
message = MIMEText(msg)
message['to'] = reciever
message['from'] = sender
message['subject'] = subject
raw = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(message.as_bytes())
raw = raw.decode()
body = {'raw' : raw}
message = (service.users().messages().send(userId='me', body=body).execute())
```

Please also note that this code only works for text that is put through the mail.

P.S. I am using Python 3.8 so the above code might not work for Python 2.